# Process Limited number Of Request while buffering rest of them

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, parallel-processing, blockingcollection

I have a requirement where i have to make a lot of db calls from streaming data. In order to keep the pool from ex hosting i had to keep the calls limited. 
After some research i have came up with an idea of using `BlockingCollection`.
Where i push the data to the `BlockingCollection` object and using the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` i keep listening to the messages

Here is how it is done

```
public BlockingCollection<ModelType> dataValues = new BlockingCollection<ModelType>(boundedCapacity: _poolLimit);


public void StartBlockingCollectionListen()
{
  foreach (var data in dataValues.GetConsumingEnumerable())
  {
     if (dataValues != null)
     {
         // send out for execution 
     }
   }
}
```

I have called the StartBlockingCollectionListen function in the app start so that it starts listening when the app is up.

Questions:

1. Is it ok to do this? [ Will this affect the performance when bulk amount of data is comming ]
2. Is there any other way to implement following requirement

   a. when data comes put it in queue

   b. check if more requests are running in parallel [ i have this with me ]

   c. if yes add it to the queue

   d. else take the first item from the queue and process. [ all the data in the queue should be processed. ]

I was hoping some methods like Observable concurrentqueue. But i didn't get any info on these.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Your direction is correct. This is what is called the Producer-Consumer problem, where the speed of producers and consumers may be grossly mismatched. What you need to pay attention to is: 1. How many items can be stored in your blocking collection, before you run out of memory? You need to avoid OOM issue. 2. What happens when such processes crash? How do you recover without losing data

Comment: @Vikhram, Thanks for your input, can you tell what will happen when the message comes in after boundedCapacity is exceeded.

Comment: It will put the thread into wait state. The wait will be broken when a item is removed from the bounded list. Checkout the example on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples)